# How do I fix a "Failed to instantiate optional component" for hudson.plugins on Mac OSX 10.13.3 in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, hudson

**My Setup and Execution Info:**

I installed Jenkins version 2.138.1 on Mac Powerbook OSX High Sierra 10.13.3.

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

I instantiate Jenkins using the command:

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8081
```

I get the following **Log File Message:**

```
Failed to instantiate optional component hudson.plugins.build_timeout.operations.AbortAndRestartOperation$DescriptorImpl; skipping;
```

**MY QUESTIONS:**

1) Is this benign or important for installation and execution, and why?

2) How do I correct this?

Thanks, in advance, for any help you can offer.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this.  I'm having a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an issue (https://github.com/jenkinsci/build-timeout-plugin/issues/67) reported on the plugin's GitHub repository. It's not fixed yet.